# filter elements by attribute value between two others values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to filter elements by attribute value ***data-price=""*** between two others values. i'm using jquery ui slider for the price range.

HTML:

```
<div class="content" data-price="500">500</div>
<div class="content" data-price="600">600</div>
<div class="content" data-price="700">700</div>
<div class="content" data-price="800">700</div>
<div class="content" data-price="900">900</div>
<div class="content" data-price="1000">1000</div>
<div class="content" data-price="5000">5000</div>
<div class="content" data-price="10000">10000</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider({
            range:true,
           min: 0,
           max: 20000,
           values: [ 500, 20000 ],
           slide: function( event, ui ) {
              $( "#price" ).val( "€" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - €" + ui.values[ 1 ] ); 
           },

           //if(i.values[ 0 ] < data-price < i.values[ 1 ]){
           //     show filtered element
           //} else { hide the rest }
        });
});
```

when i try to print $(".content") in the console , i see just the first element .

Comment: Can you post a demo of your (minimal/[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) code to reproduce the problem, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar?

Comment: I wonder how your code might work at all. This line is completely invalid in JS: `if(i.values[ 0 ] < data-price < i.values[ 1 ])`

Comment: it's just to show my idea , how i would like to make , is not a code

Comment: @hindmost my fault , i commented it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery filter function, for example

```
var min = 700;
var max = 1000;

$('.content').filter(function(){
  return $(this).data('price') < min || $(this).data('price') > max;
}).hide();
```